# Using multiple ML .net models

Tags: .net, .net-core, artificial-intelligence

I have a project where I need to recommend an employee to execute a task depending on their previous record of handling the said type of tasks(the idea would be to select an employee that has the highest predicted chance of completing the task correctly and on time). Thing is that at the moment as I imagine it - each employee should have his own model that would need to be trained and tested in order to perform the prediction at the highest accuracy. I would appreciate any advice or opinion!

Comment: Sounds like a recommender system scenario.  https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-recommender-systems-6c66cf15ada

Comment: Thank you for the column! Appreciate it!